# Automatically tag newly shared files?

Tags: mac, finder, automator, mojave, finder-tag

I'm loosing track of all my shared iCloud files throughout my Mac. Is there a way to automatically tag newly shared files with a tag called `Shared` for example, then remove the tag when it is no longer shared?

I tried creating a Workflow via Automator, but I didn't see anything like this. Is there a way to do this or a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You’re gonna need some toolset: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/enterprise/file_management/files_tagging.html
Hope that helps